# Distinct() returns duplicates with a user-defined type

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq query which returns an array of objects, with unique values in their constructors.  For integer types, Distinct returns only one copy of each value, but when I try creating my list of objects, things fall apart.  I suspect it's a problem with the equality operator for my class, but when I set a breakpoint, it's never hit.

Filtering out the duplicate int in a sub-expression solves the problem, and also saves me from constructing objects that will be immediately discarded, but I'm curious why this version doesn't work.

**UPDATE: 11:04 PM**  Several folks have pointed out that MyType doesn't override GetHashCode().  I'm afraid I oversimplified the example.  The original MyType does indeed implement it.  I've added it below, modified only to put the hash code in a temp variable before returning it.

Running through the debugger, I see that all five invocations of GetHashCode return a different value. And since MyType only inherits from Object, this is presumably the same behavior Object would exhibit.

Would I be correct then to conclude that the hash should instead be based on the contents of Value?  This was my first attempt at overriding operators, and at the time, it didn't appear that GetHashCode needed to be particularly fancy.  (This is the first time one of my equality checks didn't seem to work properly.)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] list = { 1, 3, 4, 4, 5 };
        int[] list2 =
            (from value in list
             select value).Distinct().ToArray();    // One copy of each value.
        MyType[] distinct =
            (from value in list
             select new MyType(value)).Distinct().ToArray(); // Two objects created with 4.

        Array.ForEach(distinct, value => Console.WriteLine(value));
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public MyType(int arg)
    {
        Value = arg;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int retval = base.GetHashCode();
        return retval;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        MyType rhs = obj as MyType;
        if ((Object)rhs == null)
            return false;

        return this == rhs;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
    {
        bool result;

        if ((Object)lhs != null && (Object)rhs != null)
            result = lhs.Value == rhs.Value;
        else
            result = (Object)lhs == (Object)rhs;

        return result;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented GetHashCode()? Looks like you could return Value.HashCode()

Comment: You are essentially implementing a value type in your MyClass reference type.  There's nothing wrong with that, but you do need to think in terms of the value of MyClass being the identity of the instance instead of the object's location in memory being its identity (the default for reference types).  Thus, override GetHashCode() to return Value.GetHashCode() to reflect that identity.

Comment: @dthorpe - I think my main problem was a failure to recognize how GetHashCode was likely to be implemented in Object. My thinking at the time was essentially, "I don't need anything fancy, the default implementation should be good enough."  I won't make that mistake again.  Next time I go to override operator==, I'll find an entirely different way to mess it up.

Comment: @Blair: That's the spirit!  ;>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override GetHashCode() in your class.  GetHashCode must be implemented in tandem with Equals overloads. It is common for code to check for hashcode equality before calling Equals.  That's why your Equals implementation is not getting called.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect - according to the docs, Distinct() uses the default equality comparer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

Comment: Reworded. The point is, the original poster noted that his Equals implementation is not getting called at all. Reason? The system that performs the equality comparison (Default equality comparer, whatever) checks the hashcode before calling Equals. He hasn't overridden GetHashCode, so the hash values will never be the same so his Equals implementation will never be called.  If he fixes the GetHashCode() problem, then he will probably figure out on his own that he also has bugs in his Equals implementation.

Comment: `Distinct` uses a `Set<T>` to keep track of which items have been seen before, and `Set<T>` uses `GetHashCode()` internally.

Comment: Yes, you are both right - the documentation is very unclear on this.

Comment: Even after adding the missing GetHashCode(), I still don't see any of the equalities being called.  Presumably this is because the default GetHashCode() returns a different value for every distinct object and no further checking is deemed necessary.

Comment: Did you implement GetHashCode to return a value appropriate to the contents of your object?  So that Obj A with Value 1 has the same hash code as Object B with Value 1?  (Hint: you probably want to return Value.GetHashCode())

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I reached last night, just wanted to see if I could get independent confirmation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion is correct,it is the equality which currently just checks the object references. Even your implementation does not do anything extra, change it to this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    MyType rhs = obj as MyType;
    if ((Object)rhs == null)
        return false;

    return this.Value == rhs.Value;
}
```

Comment: Equals defers to the overridden == that compares values.

Comment: What are you on about @Henk?? The point is this needs to be added this.Value == rhs.Value.

Comment: Changing that last line to compare the Value property makes the filtering work, but the real MyType has multiple properties to compare.  Do I really need to compare them all?  It's tempting to write it as return (MyType)this == (MyType)rhs, but that would head off into recursion....

Comment: @TheBlairGuy  MyType has got one property -> Value. Even when they do have more than one it suffice to compare the id,

Answer (score 2):

In you equality method you are still testing for reference equality, rather than semantic equality, eg on this line:

```
result = (Object)lhs == (Object)rhs
```

you are just comparing two object references which, even if they hold exactly the same data, are still not the same object.  Instead, your test for equality needs to compare one or more properties of your object.  For instance, if your object had an ID property, and objects with the same ID should be considered semantically equivalent, then you could do this:

```
result = lhs.ID == rhs.ID
```

Note that overriding Equals() means you should also override GetHashCode(), which is another kettle of fish, and can be quite difficult to do correctly.

Comment: As others pointed out, this doesn't explain why the OP's override of Equals is never called - and the solution is to override GetHashCode() too.  This is fraught with difficulties, so I made another suggestion in a new answer.

Comment: At this point, I believe part of the problem is my implementation of GetHashCode().  Instead of simply returning base.GetHashCode(), it looks like I need to return something based on Value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement GetHashCode().

Comment: This is true only in that it should always be done when overriding Equals(), but on its own will not solve the questioner's problem.

Comment: Mikey Cee: If `GetHashCode()` doesn't return the same value for two object, `Equals()` will never get called.

Comment: Mikey Cee: But it does answer the questioner's question of why his breakpoint in Equals never gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a simple Distinct operation can be implemented more elegantly as follows:

```
var distinct = items.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => x.First());
```

where ID is the property that determines if two objects are semantically equivalent.  From the confusion here (including that of myself), the default implementation of Distinct() seems to be a little convoluted.

Comment: In the real-world code, I've used a nested query to filter out the duplicate int.  This has definitely been an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I think MyType needs to implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this to work.

Comment: Sorry - my bad - I've just implemented IEquatable<T> before to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have pretty much covered the fact that you need to implement Equals and GetHashCode correctly, but as a side note you may be interested to know that anonymous types have these values implemented automatically:

```
var distinct =
        (from value in list
         select new {Value = value}).Distinct().ToArray();
```

So without ever having to define this class, you automatically get the Equals and GetHashCode behavior you're looking for.  Cool, eh?